# Create a column that increments for each unique ID in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
ID     Minutes Read    Comprehension     
1      25              1      
1      30              1      
2      20              2      
2      25              2     
2      30              1
```

I want to create a column called "day" that counts the days each person reported reading, such as below:

```
ID     Minutes Read    Comprehension     Day  
1      25              1                 1
1      30              1                 2
2      20              2                 1
2      25              2                 2
2      30              1                 3
```

How would I go about doing that? The end goal is to use the "day" column to reshape my data,

`df2 <- reshape(df, idvar="ID", timevar = "day", direction="wide")`.

Comment: `reshape(transform(df, time = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq)), dir = 'wide', idvar = 'ID')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your aim is to reshape the data, try:

```
reshape(transform(df, time = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq)), dir = 'wide', idvar = 'ID')

  ID Minutes.Read.1 Comprehension.1 Minutes.Read.2 Comprehension.2 Minutes.Read.3 Comprehension.3
1  1             25               1             30               1             NA              NA
3  2             20               2             25               2             30               1
```

If you are only interested in the `day` column, then

```
df <- transform(df, day = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(day = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = day,
    values_from = c(MinutesRead, Comprehension)
  )
```

```
     ID MinutesRead_1 MinutesRead_2 MinutesRead_3 Comprehension_1 Comprehension_2 Comprehension_3
  <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>           <int>           <int>           <int>
1     1            25            30            NA               1               1              NA
2     2            20            25            30               2               2               1
```

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MinutesRead = c(25L, 
30L, 20L, 25L, 30L), Comprehension = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as a one-liner:

```r
df$Day <- unlist(sapply(rle(df$ID)$lengths, seq_len))

df
  ID Minutes.Read Comprehension Day
1  1           25             1   1
2  1           30             1   2
3  2           20             2   1
4  2           25             2   2
5  2           30             1   3
```

Comment: See Onyambu's comment on my answer; this won't work in case `ID` is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `lapply`**

We first call to `split()` to split `df` by ID. The output of `split` is a list, so we use `lapply` to perform the task on each element (i.e. ID) of that list. Then, we compute the number of rows per ID and use `seq_len` to create a sequence of numbers from 1 to the number of rows per ID. Finally, we `rbind`, so that we are returned a `data.frame`.

```
df <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) cbind(x, Day = seq_len(nrow(x))))
)
rownames(df) <- NULL # optional

#> str(df$Day)
# int [1:5] 1 2 1 2 3
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 Minutes = c(25,30,20,25,30),
                 Comprehension = c(1,1,2,2,1))
```

Comment: Just use `unlist(tapply(df$ID, df$ID, seq))`, although all these methods will assume the data is ordered. eg `x <- c('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b')` should give `c(1,1,2,3,2,3)` but using `rle/tapply` you wont get these results

Comment: Since `ID` in OP's example was in ascending order, I thought of also including these options. But it's indeed saver not to do so, in case other users, whose data is not sorted, will use these methods and experience troubles. Edited, thanks.